# Multithread text output without without blinking

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I had to write some program with multithred text out using ncurses library for Linux terminal. I tried to do it like I show below, but it work badly. Do you have any ideas how to organise for working well?

```
#include <panel.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main()
{
  pthread_t t_out[5];
  for(i=1; i<13; i++)
    pthread_create(&t_out[i],NULL,&text_out,&i);
  pthread_t refr[5];
    pthread_create(&t_out[i],NULL,&refresh_all,NULL);
}

void text_out(void *coord)
{
  int x = *(int *)coord;
  int i;
  for(i=1; i<10; i++)
  {
    move(i,x);
    printw("*");
    sleep(1);
  }
}


void refresh_all()
{
  while(1)
  {
    clear();
    refresh();
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly works badly?

Comment: at first look, few things are messy in the snippet you have pasted. first array t_out has of size 5 and you are dereferencing it till 12.Secondly you have probably created refr and never used that, and instead passed t_out again to pthread_create.

Comment: @mawia, you absolutely right about it but I write it like that only because it rough sketch. The main problem is a blinking of the output text and I wounder how to fix blinking.

Comment: Why do you think your text_out threads will see different *coord values?

Comment: @user1447446 it is better to put not so rough 'rough sketch' otherwise it become very hard for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to me you're clearing the screen 5 times a second, no wonder it blinks.

Anyway, it's best to keep the same practice UI frameworks everywhere use - keep your UI in one thread.